# How to create a fixed size virtual disk with qemu-img?

Tags: linux, virtualization, ls, qemu

What's the best way to create a fixed size disk with qemu-img ? 
I tried doing this., and it always seems to be creating a virtual /growing disk, doing a ls returns the actual small size of the vmdk.

is there a way to create a "fixed size" disk?

```
root@local:/tmp# qemu-img create -f vmdk test.vmdk 2G
Formatting 'test.vmdk', fmt=vmdk size=2147483648 compat6=off zeroed_grain=off

root@local:/tmp# qemu-img info test.vmdk
image: test.vmdk
file format: vmdk
virtual size: 2.0G (2147483648 bytes)
disk size: 12K

root@local:/tmp# ls -lah test.vmdk
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 320K May 13 09:15 test.vmdk
```

Comment: While the answer by user319088 checked out, I want to comment that if other user come here looking for way to create a fixed size, native .qcow2 image, I have not found a way. Even converting from flat vmdk does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The vmdk disk can be created with `-o subformat=monolithicFlat` option.  A flat disk image fills unused space.  Doc: [`qemu-img create` options](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/6.0/tools/qemu-img.html#cmdoption-qemu-img-commands-arg-create) and [vmdk format](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/6.0/system/images.html#cmdoption-image-formats-arg-vmdk).